# Demodule qpsk in lol

Tags: matlab

I have a phone number in a signal() and I know that the sampling frequency is 8000hz.  Using the command **spectrogram**, how can I determine the phone number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you generated test signals to verify code?
Have a look at the following Matlab code.

```
% sampling frequency
fs = 8000;

% sample instants (100 ms)
t = 0 : 1/fs : 100e-3 - 1/fs;

% test frequencies
f1 = 941; %697;
f2 = 1209; %1633;

% generate test signal
tone1 = sin(2*pi*f1*t);
tone2 = sin(2*pi*f2*t);
sig = tone1 + tone2;

%window = ones(100, 1); % rectangular window
%window = hamming(100); % Hamming window
noverlap = 0;
nfft = 1024;

spectrogram(sig, window, noverlap, nfft, fs);

s = spectrogram(sig, window, noverlap, nfft, fs);

figure;
plot( abs( s ) )
```

And also check out the generated plot in figure 2.
You can play around with different test tone frequencies and windows (e.g. rectangular, Hamming, Hanning, Blackman, etc). You will see how sharp the peaks of the tones in the spectrum is (concerning spectral smearing and leakage).

The number `nfft` determines the number of coefficients calculated in the FFT. This relates to your frequency resolution in the diagram.

It might be a bit of an overkill to calculate the whole spectrogram. As you can see in the plotted spectrum and the test tone generation again: DTMF consists of two tones. Therefore the maximum of the spectrogram will also return you only one frequency if I am right.

Furthermore calculating the whole spectrogram may be an overkill as it's quite computationally complex. You could just compute the DFT components of the given DTMF frequencies (=4 rows + 4 columns = 8 frequencies to evaluate).